# Работа с массивом из введеных данных

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как заполнить массив из введенных данных в цикле и проверить на наличие некоторых элементов?

Comment: 5 элементов `items = [input() for _ in range(5)]`, проверка на наличие `"999"` в списке: `if "999" in items:`

Answer (score 1):

```
mas = []
while True:
    p = input('Enter char: ')
    if p == '0': break #проверка, если ввели 0, то закончить ввод данных
    mas.append(p)
print(mas)
```

Comment: А зачем целым числом проверять условие цикла, чем `True`/`False` не устроил? :)